# How to access/reference specific dimensions of a Numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

Suppose I have a 3-D array x, I know I could do:

```
x[:,ind,:] = y
```

but what if x is a N-D array and I want to put an index (ind) in its M-th dimension.

I tried to use `numpy.take` like `x.take(ind, axis=M)`, but this returns a copy of the sliced array instead of a reference.

Does Numpy provide any function for this?

Comment: Yes, `insert` and `put`. In this case if you want to replace an item you can use `put`.

Answer (score 0):

You can first create the index using `slice` and then apply it:

```
>>> index = [slice(None)]*N
>>> index[M] = ind
>>> x[index] = y
```